# Don't save the value in extra field in IdentityRole

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

In IdentityFramework I add new field for my database the standart table Role(Description),[image]

When I add the new role, I want to have the description for this role.

I make the cshtml file

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateRole", "Role", FormMethod.Post))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<div id="create-role-box">
    @Html.ValidationSummary(false)

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="create-role-color">Название роли:</label>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name, new { @class = "input-form-create-role create-role-color" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Name)
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="create-role-color">Описание роли:</label>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Description, new { @class = "input-form-create-role create-role-color" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Description)
    </div>

    <div class="form-group" style="margin: 22px 0px 0px 0px;">
        <button type="submit" class="button-create-role">Добавить</button>

        @Html.ActionLink("Отмена", "Index", null, new { @class = "button-cancel" })
    </div>
</div>
```

}

post query in controller

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> CreateRole([Required]string name, string description)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            IdentityResult result = await roleManager.CreateRoleAsync(name, description);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                AddErrorsFromResult(result);
            }
        }
        return View(name);
    }
```

the `CreateRoleAsync(name, description);` method i discribe in repository

```
 public async Task<IdentityResult> CreateRoleAsync(string name, string description)
    {
        IdentityResult result = await userRole.CreateAsync(new UserRole(name, description));
        return result;
    }
```

and my `UserRole` model is

```
public class UserRole : IdentityRole
{
    public UserRole(string name, string description) : base(name)
    {
        description = Description;
    }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

and if it's need my context

```
public class IdentityUserContext : IdentityDbContext<UserModel>
{
    public IdentityUserContext() : base("UserIdentityDbContext")
    {

    }
    // creating method realize by ninject in Ninject.Web.Common.cs WebUI->App_Start
}
```

the problem is that the `description` doesn't save in database,[image: problem],

it's null but the method take the value of the `description,` why id isn't save in database.

Comment: could you please explain => `if i delete the description the role will create without any problem.`? whats the description means here? its a column in table or field in your program

Comment: just a moment need to correct my question, that fail because the validation isn't work

Comment: @remk93 does your view contain something like `RoleViewModel`?

Comment: `@model Domain.Entity.UserRole`  the problem is the validating, i delete all of them and it work, but i rewrite the question (it have bigger problem for me),sorry if someone waste the time for my question.

Comment: Okay! Follow my full code! I am answering it thoroughly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First rename your `UserRole` class to `ApplicationRole` as follows because `UserRole` is confusing. `UserRole` should be named for User and Role many-to-many join table.

```
public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
{
    public ApplicationRole(string name) : base(name){}

    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Now create a `RoleViewModel` as follows:

```
public class RoleViewModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [Display(Name = "RoleName")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Then your `Create` view:

```
@model Domain.ViewModels.RoleViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    // Your input fields and submit button here
}
```

Now write your `CreateRole` Post method as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> CreateRole(RoleViewModel roleViewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var role = new ApplicationRole(roleViewModel.Name);
        role.Description = roleViewModel.Description; // <--- Here you have to assign the `Description` value

        var roleresult = await RoleManager.CreateAsync(role);
        if (!roleresult.Succeeded)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", roleresult.Errors.First());
            return View();
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View();
}
```

Now everything will work fine!

---

If you want to create role from your repository method then write your `CreateRoleAsync` repository method as follows:

```
public async Task<IdentityResult> CreateRoleAsync(ApplicationRole applicationRole)
{
    IdentityResult result = await userRole.CreateAsync(applicationRole);
    return result;
}
```

Then call it in controller method as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> CreateRole(RoleViewModel roleViewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var role = new ApplicationRole(roleViewModel.Name);
        role.Description = roleViewModel.Description; // <--- Here you have assign the Description value

        IdentityResult result = await roleManager.CreateRoleAsync(role); // <-- call your repository method here.

        if (!roleresult.Succeeded)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", roleresult.Errors.First());
            return View();
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View();
}
```

Comment: @remk93 Now read my whole answer first thoroughly and then do exactly what I have done here. Hope your problem will go away.

Comment: I understand all what you write in answer. Thank you for helping!)
but you must write ApplicationRole instead of RoleViewModel in the method argument, it's small typo

Comment: @remk93 Yes! You are absolutely correct! Thank you. I have updated the answer.